# Excel COM Add-in installation permanently

Tags: excel, plugins, registry, excel-addins, excel-dna

I have an Excel COM add-in which is written with Excel DNA in xll format which should be enabled permanently. As I plan to install it to multiple machines.

My attempt is to create the below registry keys. The binary is located in C:\MyPlugin\MyPlugin.xll. However, it cannot be loaded when Excel is launched. Could anyone please advise what is missing?

Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\Excel\Addins\MyPlugin
Name: LoadBehavior
Type: REG_DWORD
Data: 3

Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\Excel\AddinsData\MyPlugin
Name: LoadCount
Type: REG_DWORD
Data: 0

Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\OfficeCompat\Excel\AddinCleanLoad
Name: C:\MyPlugin\MyPlugin.xll
Type: REG_DWORD
Data: 233b004e

Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\OfficeCompat\Excel\AddinUsage
Name: C:\MyPlugin\MyPlugin.xll
Type: REG_DWORD
Data: 1000000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution worked.
https://docs.excel-dna.net/installing-your-add-in/

Registry key is installed in HKCU, so I additionally set run key to initiate the XLL when the machine is started for each user's initial run.